# Adding two numbers together in a for loop

Tags: batch-file

Ok, so I'm creating a simple batch file that's meant to get lines from a text file, then pipe the output to wget and download them (Using the Windows port). The only issue I'm having is adding a number to a number within the for loop.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set sum=0
%ECHO% "Reading %1... "

for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%1) do ( 
    echo %%a | bin\wget -q %%a
    SET /a sum=%sum%+1
    echo Hit:%sum% %%a 
)

%ECHO% "Done!"
ENDLOCAL
```

It's being called like 'call read_line.bat myfile.txt

Yes, I know I could just use wget -i myfile.txt, but I'd prefer to not use that and have control on other things (Output, and The obvious HIT: function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `!` instead of `%` for `sum` in order to really use delayed expansion:

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%1) do ( 
  echo %%a | bin\wget -q %%a
  SET /a sum=!sum!+1
  echo Hit:!sum! %%a 
)
```

Comment: You may also omit any expansion in `SET /a` command because it does not need it: `SET /a sum=sum+1` or, better yet: `SET /a sum+=1`